# jQuery - How to get the index of an elment relative to its selection (not it's parent)

Tags: jquery, indexing, selection

If I have a structure like this:

```
<ul>
     <li>Foo</li>
     <li>Man</li>
     <li>Choo</li>
</ul>
<ul>
     <li>Tom</li>
     <li class="active">Dick</li>
     <li>Harry</li>
</ul>
```

And I do a selection like this:

```
jQuery('li.active').index();
```

The result will be 1, when what I want is it to be 5 (or 4 if zero based counting).

How do I do that? I'm sure it's super easy and I'm just drawing a blank.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap this structure in a container div:

```
<div id="list">
    <ul>
         <li>Foo</li>
         <li>Man</li>
         <li>Choo</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
         <li>Tom</li>
         <li class="active">Dick</li>
         <li>Harry</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then, you can use this jQuery:

```
$("#list li").index($("#list li.active"));   // gives you 4
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KRqZp/.

This builds a jQuery object of all the li tags.  It then finds the index in that list of the one that is `li.active` which I believe is what you want.

There are multiple ways to use `.index()` depending upon how it's used.  This particular method returns which item in the previous selector matches the parameter you passed to `.index()`.

Comment: I tried your fiddle in Fire Fox, Chrome, and IE8 and it worked in all of them.

Comment: I have a permanent working example here: http://labs.funkhausdesign.com/examples/jquery/elements-relative-postion.html

A wrapping DIV is not required.

Comment: But, it's a bad idea not to have a wrapping div because if another `<li>` tag is added anywhere else on the page, the code may break.  Good code is not that brittle.  I try not to recommend brittle code.

Comment: @jfriend: I understand, I made the question way more simple than it really is. Just pointing out to anyone else that it is possible without the wrapping DIV. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Index returns the position of the selected element relative to its siblings ([see docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/)).

What you'd need to try is something like this:

```
var liIndex = -1;
$('li').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
        liIndex = i;
});
```